# How do I vectorize a conditional timedelta operation?

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I wanted to avoid the for loops in Python pandas, but I didn't make it due to lack of exposure. I wanted to derive a new column based on an existing column by adding some amount of information to it.

My Scenario:

```
for each in data['days']:
    if each<100000:
        clsdate.append(datetime.now()+ relativedelta(days=each))
    else:
        clsdate.append(datetime.now())

data['clsdate'] = clsdate
```

data['days'] contains a int number. Here, I am iterating the whole column and doing the sum

> today's date + no.of days = Closing date

and appending the value to a list. Then adding the list to the dataframe based on the if condition i.e., range of the value.

How to avoid this looping and adding in a single shot.

Comment: what is `prediction`?

Comment: datetime.now(), Edited my question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use pandas' datetime functions:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['days'] = [1, 3, 2, 4]
pd.to_datetime('now') + pd.to_timedelta(df['days'], unit='days')
Out: 
0   2016-08-09 07:25:22
1   2016-08-11 07:25:22
2   2016-08-10 07:25:22
3   2016-08-12 07:25:22
Name: days, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Updated my Question. Have a check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
data['clsdate'] = data['days'].apply(lambda x: datetime.now() + relativedelta(days=x))
```

Comment: Updated my question. I have a check now.